# Gauss formula for a 3-sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Given connections $\nabla$ and $\bar{\nabla}$ as connections on $\mathbb{R}^4$ and the 3-sphere of radius $r$: $\mathbb{S}^3(r)$, the vector fields $X,Y$ tangent to $\mathbb{S^3}(r)$, how do I obtain the expression:
$$\nabla_{X} Y = \bar\nabla_{X} Y - \dfrac{1}{r^2}<X,Y>p,$$
where $p : \mathbb{S}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ represents the position vector.

I came across this expression in a paper which mentions it as a standard result. However I was unable to derive it from my own limited knowledge.

Comment: There is a result that tells you that the Levi-Civita connection of an embedded manifold is obtained by an orthogonal projection of the Levi-Civita connection of the ambient manifold (you can verify this by checking the properties of the so-obtained connection). This means that
$$\begin{aligned}
\nabla_XY&=\left[\nabla_XY\right]^\top+\left[\nabla_XY\right]^\perp\\
& =\bar\nabla_XY+\left\langle\nabla_XY,\frac{p}{r}\right\rangle\frac{p}{r}\\
& =\bar\nabla_XY+\frac{1}{r^2}\left\langle\nabla_XY,p\right\rangle p\\
\end{aligned}.$$Can you go on from here?

Comment: @frog.Thanks a lot. Most of what you said is clear, excpet for the second step. How is $[\nabla_X Y]^{\perp} = < \nabla_X Y , \dfrac{p}{r}>\dfrac{p}{r}$. Oh and since your comment is almost an answer, I would be more than happy to accept it if you write it up as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Levi-Civita connection of an embedded manifold is obtained by an orthogonal projection of the Levi-Civita connection of the ambient manifold (see comment). In particular,
$$\begin{aligned}
\nabla_XY&=\left[\nabla_XY\right]^\top+\left[\nabla_XY\right]^\perp\\
& =\bar\nabla_XY+\left\langle\nabla_XY,\frac{p}{r}\right\rangle\frac{p}{r}\\
& =\bar\nabla_XY+\frac{1}{r^2}\left\langle\nabla_XY,p\right\rangle p\\
\end{aligned}$$
Now, since the $\mathbb R^4$ is equipped with the flat metric, this means that $\nabla_XY=X(Y)$. Hence you obtain
$$
\langle\nabla_XY,p\rangle = \underbrace{X\langle Y,p\rangle}_{=0} -\langle Y,X(p)\rangle=-\langle X,Y\rangle,
$$
since $p$ is the inclusion map.

Comment: No prob, what are the doubts?

Comment: If the confusion is too trivial, you can just direct me to a suitable source.

Comment: One is I am a bit confused about how to interpret $<\nabla_X Y,p>$ as one is a vector field and p is a map!. Another confusion is of course as to how $[\nabla_X Y]^{\perp} = <\nabla_X Y, \dfrac{p}{r}>\dfrac{p}{r}$??

Comment: You can interpret $p$ as a vector in Euclidean 4-space, that makes $p$ a vector field. For the second issue, note that the normal bundle of the sphere is one dimensional and the outer unit normal to the sphere is given by $p/r$. Does that help?

Comment: Yes it does almost. Just one last thing about the second issue, i am still a bit unclear about that precise term although I get that the outer unit normal to the sphere is $\dfrac{p}{r}$. Why is the inner product coming up as a scalar multiple of $\dfrac{p}{r}$? Thanks anyways. You have been tremendously helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the previous overload of questions, that term is quite clear now, just the second fundamental form at work, I really need to get my basics stronger. Everything is resolved.

Comment: Ok great :-). You're very welcome.